# Multiline URL break in PDF to PDF/A conversion

Tags: urls, pdf-a

I need to convert PDF output of latex to PDFA. The problem is that in references, where url is more than one line, the converted url only contains the first line.

For example

```
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions

/ask/page.html
```

Converts to

```
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) thesis template.

I use these commands to convert PDF tp PDF/A:

```
pdftops PDFOriginal.pdf PDFOriginal.ps
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=MyOutPutPDF-A.pdf PDFOriginal.ps
```

Edit: I tried [this](http://thisthatisnot.blogspot.it/2010/04/free-way-to-convert-existing-pdf-to.html) solution. First I created Java file in the same path. Then when I run `java FixPrintFlag Out_PDFA.pdf New_verifiablePDFA.pdf` I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class FixPrintFlag
```

Comment: I found this: http://thisthatisnot.blogspot.it/2010/04/free-way-to-convert-existing-pdf-to.html is there any easier solution?

Comment: I modified the question with a solution I tried, but I get an error. Please somebody help. This is very urgent

Comment: In the end, I solved the problem with adobe acrobat reader pro virtual printer.

Comment: Can you convert you last comment into an answer so other user can find it?

Comment: I don't know which question is adopted for the answer! The answer I delete was for the wrong question. isn't it?

Comment: Concerning your deleted answer: I think you are using `\section*{}` to remove the appendix from the headline on top of the slides? That is the right solution, but the questions you posted it at was about the frame numbers at the bottom of the slides - so another topic.

Comment: My suggestion for you is to convert your comment about using adobe acrobat reader pro virtual printer into an answer to this question -- self-answers are perfectly fine to do on this site and others will know that you questions was solved.

Comment: Why do you convert to PS before creating the PDF/A file? You can/should feed the PDF file directly.